# What can cause MySQL to accidentally execute the same operation twice in the same second?

Tags: mysql, index

For the past couple months, I've been seeing a lot of these errors: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry`

The proximate cause is that I have a unique composite index on columns `note` and `created_at`.

But what could the *root* cause be? Is there ever something in MySQL that causes a hiccup where an operation runs twice?  Or is this something that is definitely happening at the app code level?

(I'm not an expert at MySQL tuning and all the config settings available, but I do remember that certain settings have tradeoffs between performance and consistency/reliability, so I'm wondering whether there are certain settings or environmental conditions that might lead my DB to lose track of whether it has written something, and then it occasionally tries to write twice.)

I have been unable to reproduce the issue; I've never figured out how to get a write operation to happen twice within the same second *intentionally*.

My Ubuntu Docker server has 1GB RAM and not much traffic.

P.S. I also see a lot of these errors in the log: `PDO::prepare(): MySQL server has gone away` and `E_WARNING: Error while sending STMT_PREPARE packet. PID=10` but not at the same time as this integrity constraint violation error.

Comment: The most likely explanation is a double-click on your web site.

Comment: Is it possible to create two notes in a single second?  My point here is that having a Datetime as part of a unique key is asking for this kind of trouble.

Comment: @RickJames The `note` field is the actual content of the note, and in my app, it would make no sense for that same note to be posted twice within the same second. The unique composite index that I currently have on columns `note` and `created_at` isn't an index I really want; it's just temporary to help me diagnose what the heck is going on here and prevent my DB from getting cluttered with these double-posts. Unlike Michael's suggestion, double-clicking a submit button doesn't seem to be the cause. Thanks.